# How to add JSON API to ASP.NET Core 2.2 project

Tags: asp.net

I need to convert this simple json format in ASP.NET Core:

```
[{
"id":1", 
"name":"product_1"
}]
```

In that Json Format

```
  {
    "data": {
      "type": "products",
      "id": "1",
      "attributes": {
       "name": "product_1"
       }
    },
    "meta": {
      "verified" : false
    }
  }
```

Comment: Please, clarify. You want to reply with JSON or accept JSON?

Comment: both, since I will implement frontend with ngx-jsonapi of angular, and this one uses this format

Comment: Take a look at [this helpful resource](https://andrewlock.net/model-binding-json-posts-in-asp-net-core/). Please, next time append your code too.

Answer (score 0):

If your json data is represented as a class, you could transform this into another class and send it through a serializer (e.g. Newtonsoft JSON).

Your initial format could be represented as a class. Actually as a List of that class.

Example:

```
 public class InitialJsonFormat {
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public string Name {get;set;}
 }
```

You need to model your data, so that it can be serialized.

```
public class JsonData {
  public string Id { get;set;}
  public string Type { get;set;}
  //...
  public List<JsonAttribute> { get;set;}
}

public class JsonAttribute {
  public string Name { get;set;}
}
public class JsonMetaData {
  public bool Verified { get;set;}
}
```

Your Json-Document could be a class itself, built from instances of the classes before.

```
public class JsonDocument {
  public JsonData Data {get;set;}
  public JsonMetaData Meta {get;set;}
}
```

Newtonsoft JSON should serialize it the way you described it. To fill your objects you could write a "converter"-class that instantiates those objects and fills it.